# Where can I find Wielandt's original proof of Sylow's Theorem?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, soft-question, finite-groups, alternative-proof

I have seen several proofs of Sylow's Theorem based on Wielandt's method. Everyone gives credit to Wielandt's proof of Sylow's theorem, but ironically everyone puts their own spin on it.

**Where can I find the original Wielandt's proof of Sylow's theorem?**

Comment: Apparently in: H. Wielandt. Ein Beweis fuer die Existenz der Sylowgruppen. Archiv der Mathematik, 10:401–402, 1959. Temporary link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/o9n9hwelta1wy2k/wielandt.pdf?dl=0

Comment: https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/techreports/UCAM-CL-TR-452.pdf

Comment: @mesel *"The theorem of Sylow is proved in Isabelle HOL. We follow the proof by Wielandt that is more general than the original and uses a non-trivial combinatorial identity"* $\dots$ Hence $\mathbf{not}$ Wielandt's $\mathbf{original}$ proof.

Comment: It follows same steps with more explanation.

Comment: The proof that is usually used is basically that of Wielandt, but it includes a trick of Graham Higman at the end, which avoids proving that a certain expression involving a binomial coefficient  evaluates to an integer that is congruent to $1$ modulo $p$. Higman pointed out that it has been proved that , if $k$ denotes the number of subgroups   of order $p^\beta$, where $p^\beta$ divides $|G|$, then the value of $k$ modulo $p$ depends only on $\beta$ and $|G|$. So it must take the same value for the cyclic group of order $|G|$, which is $1$.

Answer (score 3):

At the end of the Wikipedia page for that, it gave this citation:
Wielandt, Helmut Ein Beweis für die Existenz der Sylowgruppen. (German) Arch. Math. (Basel) 10 1959 401–402.

And then I found [this scanned page](https://zbmath.org/?format=complete&q=an:0092.02403) that mentions that paper in a condensed way.

My German is rusty, but I can kind of see that it says something like

> The following very simple proof for the existence of Sylow groups of a group $\def\G{\frak G}\G$ is given: Let $p^n$ be a divisor of the order $g$ of $\G$, with $p$ a prime number. We consider the $\binom g{p^n}$ subsets of cardinality $p^n$ of $\G$. On them $\G$ realises by right-multiplication a permutation representation of $\G$. As $p^{n+1}$ is not a divisor of $\binom g{p^n}$, there is some orbit [area of transitivity] of length not divisible by $p^{n+1}$. If $\frak K$ is a set in this orbit, then the stabiliser subgroup of $\frak K$  [the subgroup $\frak H$ that fixes $\frak K$] has the desired order $p^k$.

[image: scan from Zentralblatt]

Comment: Not only did your German seem rusty, the English of your translation seemed so as well. I fixed the translation, adding in square brackets some roundabout descriptions of the modern terms "orbit" and "stabiliser subgroup" that (or their German counterparts) apparently were not in use at the time.